# how to plot a stacked bar plot from multiple columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked

I am struggling to create a stacked bar plot in R that will take values from multiple columns. I tried different ways of grouping data, but I don't know how to specify the y-axis. The data looks like this. I want to plot fruit on the x-axis, then size, smell, and cost in one bar for each fruit, along with their standard errors. Not sure if this is the correct dataframe. Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
fruit       size  SE_size  smell   SE_smell  cost     SE_cost  
apple       2.5   0.02      5.3     0.05     10.21    0.02
banana      5.8   0.02      7.1     0.06     15.73    0.01
pineapple   7.2   0.02      4.3     0.01     14.12    0.02
mango       6.3   0.02      7.7     0.03     15.30    0.01
```

I tried to use the `group_by` function in `tidyverse`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the data into a long format for plotting with `ggplot2`. Since you have 2 sets of columns, we could adjust the names to make an easier pivot, but I just pivot the trait columns, then pivot the standard error columns, then bind them together (saves from typing out new names). I calculated the cumulative sum in order to plot the SE, which is usually done off the top of each bar in the stack. However, since the standard errors are so low, they will just look like a single line.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  select(-starts_with("SE_")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-fruit, names_to = "trait", values_to = "value") %>%
  bind_cols(
    .,
    df %>% select(starts_with("SE_")) %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = NULL, values_to = "SE")
  ) %>%
  arrange(fruit, desc(trait)) %>% 
  group_by(fruit) %>%
  mutate(cumulative = cumsum(value)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(fill = trait, y = value, x = fruit)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(
      x = fruit,
      ymin = cumulative - SE,
      ymax = cumulative + SE
    ),
    width = 0.4,
    colour = "black",
    alpha = 0.9,
    size = 1.3,
    position="identity"
  )
```

**Output**

[image]

Another possible option would be to just add labels and not include error bars.

```
df %>%
  select(-starts_with("SE_")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-fruit, names_to = "trait", values_to = "value") %>%
  bind_cols(
    .,
    df %>% select(starts_with("SE_")) %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = NULL, values_to = "SE")
  ) %>%
  arrange(fruit, desc(trait)) %>% 
  group_by(fruit) %>%
  mutate(cumulative = cumsum(value)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(fill = trait, y = value, x = fruit)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  geom_label(aes(y = cumulative, label = paste(value, "\ub1", SE)), nudge_y = -1, size = 4,
             label.size = 0, label.r = unit(0, "pt"), fill = NA)
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(fruit = c("apple", "banana", "pineapple", "mango"
), size = c(2.5, 5.8, 7.2, 6.3), SE_size = c(0.02, 0.02, 0.02,
0.02), smell = c(5.3, 7.1, 4.3, 7.7), SE_smell = c(0.05, 0.06,
0.01, 0.03), cost = c(10.21, 15.73, 14.12, 15.3), SE_cost = c(0.02,
0.01, 0.02, 0.01)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```